# How to share simulator builds of iOS apps to users on macOS Catalina

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, macos-catalina

I want to build a simulator build locally and run it on a different macOS machine. For macs on macOS 10.14 or below, this process is easy. Find the .app file, send it to the other developer, and they can use any of the options to do so (`xcrun simctl install <simulator> <path to .app>` + `xcrun simctl launch`, dragging the .app file to their running simulator and clicking in the simulator UI).

Once the other device is running 10.15, this no longer works. When the app is launched, macOS (**not** in the simulated iOS) pops up a warning modal that it is not possible to verify the app is safe, as the simulator build is unsigned/unnotarized and the application in the simulator is stuck at a white screen.

Options I've tried:

- Adding the -exportNotarizedApp option to the `xcodebuild` call. This rejects a lot of the fields needed for iOS (such as `scheme`) so is clearly meant for real mac OS apps.

Has anyone successfully shared simulator app builds on Catalina?

Do I need to actually produce a real signed simulator build? Can I use a developer cert for this?

Can I just install the same developer certificate on both machines?

The app is for internal debugging and testing and never needs to be installed on a real iOS device.

Comment: Please let me know if you find a solid solution for this, we are desperate for one but unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for notarisation is triggered by the `com.apple.quarantine` flag. This is placed on the `.app` when it was downloaded and shared and can be removed via the `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine` command prior to attempting to run it.